# Show length of selection

Tags: qgis, features, length

Today I was calculating length of features to know how long a certain route will be.
I was wondering if there is a quicker way to find out the length of a selection of features?

I am looking for a solution like a simple text in the lower status bar that says `Selection: 350 m` and maybe switches to amount of points or m² area selected according to the layer I'm on. Just in the style of Excel telling you how many cells you have selected and sum/min/max/etc of them.

Is this possible to acchieve in QGIS? In other words: am I overseeing an integrated option or is there maybe a plugin, that does that?

Comment: You might want to try the statistics panel, with $length as expression: https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html

Comment: I tried that and I get a value. Can I assume the value is in meters? It doesn't give any units...

Comment: The $length fonction respects both the current project's ellipsoid setting and distance unit settings...

Comment: You can try [this plugin](https://github.com/benwirf/measure_selected_features). Not published but if you click on the Code button on the GitHub page you can download a zip file and install it from that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may use the statistics panel (View>Panel>Statistics Panel) with the "Selected feature only" option. You will need to change the field to length or area depending on the information you want.

If length or area fields don't exist in your dataset you may use an expression in the statistic panel to calculate them.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the following PyQGIS script for the layer with projected coordinates. It prints the length of the selected line.

```py
def print_length(selected, deselected, clearAndSelect):
    if len(selected) == 1:
        global layer
        feature = layer.getFeature(selected[0])
        length = feature.geometry().length()
        print(length)
    
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("LAYER_NAME")[0]
layer.selectionChanged.connect(print_length)
```