Selecting straight polylines of given length in QGIS
I have a layer including streams, ditches and streams.
How could I select, by setting a minimum length, the straight   polylines corresponding mainly to canals and ditches?


select by length? > https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/452725/276

You use the word 'straight' in your title, and 'rectilinear' in your post.  Yet you highlight a bendy line.  All of this leaves me confused about what you need to do.  Perhaps you could edit your post and clarify.

This could help as you have some parameters to change the result and thus try out different settings for an optimal result: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/397907/88814

Select by $length and sinuosity:

the sinuosity of a curve, which is the ratio of the curve length to
the straight (2D) distance between its endpoints.

sinuosity($geometry)<1.1 and $length>500

